# Concatenating Multiple ng-class Conditions

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a `<td>` using `ng-class` with an existing condition check.

**HTML with AngularJS**

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells" ng-class="{selected: cell.isSelected, winner: cell.isWinner}" ng-click="updateCell(cell)">
    {{cell.word}}
</td>
```

I'm trying to apply a CSS class to a specific `<td>` and discovered I could do this using the `<td>` index in the `ng-class` directive:

```
ng-class="{'myClassName':$index==12}"
```

I'm having a problem adding this to the existing `ng-class`. If I try to add it to the end of the directive, separting it with a comma, the `cell.isSelected` and `cell.isWinner` conditions stop working and myClassName doesn't get applied either. Ex:

```
ng-class="{selected: cell.isSelected, winner: cell.isWinner, 'myClassName':$index==12}"
```

The `selected: cell.isSelected` and `winner: cell.isWinner` are specific to any of `<td>` cells. The `myClassName':$index==12` is supposed to be specific only to the 13th `<td>` cell.

Should I be using a separate `ng-class` directive (which does work)?

Comment: Its really not clear what you trying to do here.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate the conditions"?

Comment: How can I concatenate both `ng-class` directives? Ex: `ng-class="{selected: cell.isSelected, winner: cell.isWinner; 'myClassName':$index==12}"`.

Comment: @MattSmith The example you have shown should work.

Comment: @RahilWazir using the semicolon to separate the two conditions in the `ng-class` directive doesn't appear to be working for me.

Comment: @MattSmith I didn't see the `;`. You mean like this `selected: cell.isSelected && winner: cell.isWinner` <= but without `&&`?

Comment: @Blazemonger I did try that it seems to invalidate the entire `ng-class` directive's conditions; cell.isSelected, cell.isWinner, and myClassName are don't work when I separate with a comman.

Comment: "Don't work" doesn't explain anything to us. What's happening, and what do you want to happen instead? Each class will be added or removed independently from the others. If you want them to be *dependent* on each other, you need to explain how.

Comment: I've update the question to hopefully provide more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-class` directive accepts (among other formats) an expression evaluating to an object (key is a class, value decides whether the class is applied). If you want to add another class, just add another key to the object (separated by comma, rather than by semicolon):

```
<td ng-class="{selected: cell.isSelected, winner: cell.isWinner, myClassName: ($index == 12) }">...</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand what you mean, you can try:

```
ng-class="{selected: $index==12 && cell.isSelected, winner: $index==12 && cell.isWinner}"
```

Comment: Thanks. What I'm actually trying to do is have both conditions separate, so rather than `&&`, is there is a way to concatenate both as they are into on `ng-class`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to obtain. Please try to state it in plain English, or, better, pseudo-code...

Comment: Can I combine both `ng-class` directives together? If so, how do I separate them? Is it just a semicolon; that solution isn't working for me.

Comment: Try to describe your goal. For example: `"if $index is 12 and cell.isSelected then selected class must be true; if $index is 24 and cell.isWinner then winner clas must be true"`...

Comment: I update the question to provide more clarity. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Did you try @hon2a solution? It really should match your request, and I don't see any reason why it should not work; if it doesn't, please specify what you mean with "stop working": the `selected` and `winner` classes are never applied?